# How to change layout for a single action?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have some action and I don't want to use usual layout for it. Can I indicate in action that I want to use different layout then the default one? How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Zend Documentation for layouts](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html).

Change Layout:

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('foobaz');
```

Disable Layout:

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```